# How can I Start My application on Start up of Windows in java

Tags: java, windows, swing, desktop, startup

I have My Swing Application. and What I want to do is Lunch that Application when Windows Start up. so how can I do that Can i have suggestion? and application is Desktop application.
and What to do for MAC system is there any way for MAC system for do this same?

Comment: [Run a program automatically when Windows starts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7), it's probably not as technical as some approaches, but it works...normally...This would require you to either supply a .bat file, possibly a shortcut or a Jar wrapped in an .exe

Comment: @MadProgrammer Brother please Say in some easy words na i got little bit what u trying to say. but can u explain it :)

Comment: Basically, you need to place some kind of short-cut, batch file or executable within the start up folder of the windows user.  You can't just drop a jar file in there as Windows has no idea what to do with.  So a shortcut might work or a batch file or if you have access to, some kind of executable wrapper, which will run your Jar file...

Comment: ohh yes i got it i Study your link that u have provide. thanks man and ya write that in ans i'll accept i can do that favor :)

Comment: @Krishna, you can use `exe4j` (google it to find a download link) to create an exe file for your application. Then just follow the link MadProgrammer provided.

Comment: @Trust I am doing that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But what to do for MAC os is there any way to do same thing for that?

Comment: There is, but as I understand it, it's a little more involved, as you need to provide an app bundle.  You can also configure the applications to start through the settings [Mac OS X: Setting up Login, Startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2602)

Comment: Well i and reading that link what u have provide dude. and i will ask u if i dont get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### On Windows

You could simply place an executable item in the users Startup folder, see [Run a program automatically when Windows starts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7) for more details.

This will require to supply a short-cut (which can launch the jar using java.exe) or a batch file or a executable wrapper, like [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) or [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) for example.

### On Mac

There are a few places to look for startup items:

Items can launch upon startup from the following locations:

**System Preferences > Accounts > yourusername > Login Items**
(Lion users: System Preferences > Users & Groups > yourusername > Login Items)

**/Library/LaunchAgents/ and ~/Library/LaunchAgents/** 
(Lion users: In Finder, click Go > Go to Folder > then enter the path)

**/Library/StartupItems/**
(Lion users: In Finder, click Go > Go to Folder > then enter the path)

This assumes that the application has been bundled as an application bundle.  See [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) for more details.

There may be additional requirements in the pinfo files that I've not highlighted, but these are the basics.  This is not an area I have experience in, but something I've done a little bit of research into

Take a look at:

- [Take control of startup and login items](http://www.macworld.com/article/2047747/take-control-of-startup-and-login-items.html)
- [How to set applications to automatically launch at startup](http://www.macworld.com/article/1166116/how_to_set_applications_to_automatically_launch_at_startup.html)

For more details

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Start button Picture of the Start button , click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open.
2. Open the location that contains the item you want to create a shortcut to.
3. Right-click the item, and then click Create Shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.
4. Drag the shortcut into the Startup folder.

Comment: Well +1 for Right ans dude :)

Comment: Is there any way to do that for mac too?